# Increase Bot's Limitation about create server

Tags: discord, discord-jda

I heard BOT can create Server less than 10 servers but my bot must increase about this. If i can't increase the limit My bot Will be useless or complicate

Checked Policy about discord

i mailed discord team but they always tell me they can't tell me check discord Policy

Comment: I'm unsure what you expect people to answer here, but the limit exists and cannot be circumvented. It is unlikely anyone here can help you. You haven't described your problem or goal, besides "creating servers" so we cannot offer alternatives.